# Bash - Looping Through the File

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a simple loop through all files script but it's giving me a not spected result.

I'm using a user config file to loop content (example.conf).

```
datasetA1 datasetB1 datasetC1
datasetA2 datasetB2 datasetC2
datasetA3 datasetB3 datasetC3
datasetA4 datasetB4 datasetC4
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    ramal=`cat /data/user/example.conf | awk '{ print $1 }'`
    name=`cat /data/user/example.conf | awk '{ print $2 }'`
    macid=`cat /data/user/example.conf | awk '{ print $3 }'`
    
    for ramais in ${ramal}; do
            for names in ${name}; do
                    for idmacs in ${macid}; do
                    echo "
                    [account]
                    path = /config/voip/sipAccount0.cfg
                    Enable = 1
                    Label = ${names}
                    DisplayName = ${names}
                    AuthName = ${ramais}
                    UserName = ${ramais}
                    password = ${ramais}
                    " > 001565${idmacs}.cfg
                    echo " "
                    echo "****   ${ramais} Nome ${names} Mac ${îdmacs} success provisioned ***** "
                    done
            done
    done
```

Result:

001565datasetC1.cfg

```
        [account]
        path = /config/voip/sipAccount0.cfg
        Enable = 1
        Label = datasetB1
        DisplayName = datasetB1
        AuthName = datasetA1
        UserName = datasetA1
        password = datasetA1
```

001565datasetB1.cfg

```
        [account]
        path = /config/voip/sipAccount0.cfg
        Enable = 1
        Label = datasetB1
        DisplayName = datasetB1
        AuthName = datasetA1
        UserName = datasetA1
        password = datasetA1
```

Expected

001565datasetC1.cfg

```
        [account]
        path = /config/voip/sipAccount0.cfg
        Enable = 1
        Label = datasetB1
        DisplayName = datasetB1
        AuthName = datasetA1
        UserName = datasetA1
        password = datasetA1
```

001565datasetC2.cfg

```
        [account]
        path = /config/voip/sipAccount0.cfg
        Enable = 1
        Label = datasetB2
        DisplayName = datasetB2
        AuthName = datasetA2
        UserName = datasetA2
        password = datasetA2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested loops give you the cartesian product. You need just one loop that reads all fields in a line at once:

```
while read -r ramais names idmacs
    # insert you echo commands here
    echo "example: $ramais, $names, $idmacs"
done < /data/user/example.conf
```